# How to compare the sum of amount from 2 datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to validate sum of amount from a master column to split amounts in detail columns.

I want to put into a loop a check one by one (Master and Detail), and then if no match, popup a message to the user

I have a record from a csv text file like in the below example:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10
********************************************************************************  
Master,123456789,12345,03434343,2015-05-14,2015-05-29,16,100.00,0.00,2
Detail,123456789,12345,10.0,20.0,30.0,15.0,15.0,3.0,7.0
Master,893434343,34567,03432323,2015-05-14,2015-05-29,16,100.00,0.00,2
Master,123456789,12345,03434343,2015-05-14,2015-05-29,16,100.00,0.00,2
Detail,123456789,12345,10.0,20.0,30.0,15.0,15.0,3.0,7.0
Footer,0453434,12123243,2015-05-28,0800,052015,2,200.00,AED,1531
```

From the above file, rules will be

1. Master record may or may not contain detail record
2. If Detail record found for master record, column 2 will be the same for both
3. If Detail record found for master record then Detail record sum of (4th to 10th column) master equal to Master record 8th column

I have copied the Master records into Datatable dt1, and Detail records into Datatable dt2 from the file.

How can I compare the sum of the amounts and throw an error to user for invalid matches?

Comment: What do you have so far? I assume you got as far as getting your data into a memory, so you can compare it?

Answer (score 0):

This code isnt elegant, there probably is a better way. However, Im not sure in your case, I'd have done datatables with the data. Especially as you've not shared the layout of dt1 and dt2.

```
List<String[]> results = new List<String[]>();
String[] rawdata = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\data.txt");
for (int i = 2; i < rawdata.Length; i++)
{
    String[] tmp = rawdata[i].Split(',');
    if (tmp.Length == 10)
    {
        if ((tmp[0] == "Master") && (i < rawdata.Length))
        {
            float col4;
            float col5;
            float col6;
            float col7;
            float col8;
            float col9;
            float col10;
            float sum;
            String[] tmp2 = rawdata[i + 1].Split(',');
            if (tmp2.Length == 10 && tmp2[0] == "Detail" && tmp[1] == tmp2[1] )                           
            {
                if (float.TryParse(tmp2[3], out col4) && float.TryParse(tmp2[4], out col5) && float.TryParse(tmp2[5], out col6) && float.TryParse(tmp2[6], out col7) && float.TryParse(tmp2[7], out col8) && float.TryParse(tmp2[8], out col9) && float.TryParse(tmp2[9], out col10))
                {
                    if (float.TryParse(tmp[7], out sum))
                    {
                        if (sum == col4 + col5 + col6 + col7 + col8 + col9 + col10)
                        {
                            results.Add(new String[] { tmp[1], "Matches" });
                        }
                        else results.Add(new String[] { tmp[1], "Doesnt match" });
                        continue;
                    }
                }          
            }
            results.Add(new String[] { tmp[1], "No detail" });
        }
    }
}
```

I can confirm visually that results contains all answers